# row_number () to start at #3

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm creating a `B Record` list for IRS 1099 (just in case anyone else is familiar with the process).  There are two header records (`T Record and A Record)`, which are the two first rows of the file and they need a row count as well, so when I create my `B Record`, I'd like it to start at row number 3 as the first two rows are fixed, but I can't get it to work in my select statement.

--Padded Row Number

```
select right('00000000' ++ cast(row_number () over (order by column1) as varchar (10)),8)
```

--Results

```
00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005
00000006
```

--would like;

```
00000003
00000004
00000005
00000006
```

Thanks,

Comment: Would `row_number () + 3` work?  Just a guess..

Comment: I tried that --row_number () + 2--, but couldn't seem to get syntax correct...I wish it was that easy, but Thnx for responding.  Maybe I'm missing something really simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression you need to add to isn't `row_number()`. The expression you need to add to is `row_number ()  over (order by column1)`.

```
create table test (
  column1 integer 
  );

insert into test values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

select right('00000000' + cast((row_number ()  over (order by column1)) + 2 as varchar (10)),8)
from test;
```